# Can I add a different function that is defined in my code in a vector like arrays that include function adress?

Tags: c++, vector

In this code, there are 6 different functions. They create 6 different boards for playing a game. But I don't want to create boards with `if` conditions, I want to create a `vector` that includes function addresses in it. For example, if the user wants to create board 4 for playing the game, I want to create the board like this:

```
vector<vector<cell>> a = function_array[3];
```

`cell` is an `enum` type that I declared.

Can I do this, and can somebody help me for this?

```
vector<vector<cell>> first_table();
vector<vector<cell>> second_table();
vector<vector<cell>> third_table();
vector<vector<cell>> fourth_table();
vector<vector<cell>> fifth_table();
vector<vector<cell>> sixth_table();
    
int main()
{
    int chose,board_type;
    vector<vector<vector<cell>>> functions;

    functions.push_back(first_table());
    functions.push_back(second_table());
    functions.push_back(third_table()); //in here I create all boards and print which one the user wants
    functions.push_back(fourth_table()); //but I don't want to do this, I want just create the board the user wants
    functions.push_back(fifth_table());
    functions.push_back(sixth_table());

    vector<vector<cell>> b = functions[board_type-1];
    print_game(b);
    b = functions[0];
    cout << "welcomw Game" << endl;
    cout << "Please chose board type" << endl;
    cin >> board_type;
    int game_type;
    cout << "1.Personal game " << endl << "Computer game" << endl;
    cin >> game_type;
    string input;
    cout << "Please enter move direction" << endl;
    cin >> input;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

In your case, you'd create a vector of `std::function<>` for functions that take no parameter and return a `vector<vector<cell>>`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct cell {};

//type aliases make code a lot more readable!
using board = std::vector<std::vector<cell>>;

board first_table();
board second_table();
board third_table();
board fourth_table();
board fifth_table();
board sixth_table();

int main() {
  std::vector<std::function<board()>> functions;

  functions.push_back(first_table);
  // etc...

  board b = functions[board_type-1]();
}
```

Comment: You don't really need `std::function`. It has overhead that is unnecessary for this use case. Since all of the functions have the same signature, plain function pointers will suffice, eg: `using board = vector<vector<cell>>; using board_func = board (*)(); ... board first_table(); ... std::vector<board_func> functions{ &first_table, ... }; ... board b = functions[index]();`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are technically correct (the best kind of correct!), but on the flip side, most people have a way overblown view of `std::function's` overhead The only really problematic part of it compared to raw function pointers is its `sizeof`. OPs case is one of those situations where I think a cleaner separation of concerns on the design front is worth using a handful more bytes of storage.

Comment: I have tried your code , but ı have  taken error like this;
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::function<board ()>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::function<board ()>>]" matches the argument listC/C++(304)
main.cpp(30, 12): argument types are: (board ())
main.cpp(30, 12): object type is: std::vector<std::function<board ()>, std::allocator<std::function<board ()>>>

Comment: @goOdyaga Notice that in my example, I pass `first_table` itself, as opposed to passing the result of calling `first_table()` like you did in your question. That's most likely your mistake. In any case, I assure you that the code in my answer works fine as is on all modern compilers.

Comment: you are correct because of my mistake ıt didn't work but now code is working thank you so much :)))